# Where to store TcpStream to share with BufReader and BufWriter

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, lifetime-scoping

I'm trying to build a simple client crate for a program that has it's own simple TCP protocol.

Most of the communication works by sending a command and immediately reading a single line response. Some of the commands need to read multiple responses. I've been using `BufReader::read_line()` to read single lines but this seems to fall down when it reads too much, the second `read_line()` can be missing the start of the line.

My assumption is that I'm meant to be keeping the `BufReader` around so that it keeps its internal state.

I'm doing this by passing a reference of the `TcpStream` to the `BufReader` and `BufWriter` but I'm getting “borrowed value does not live long enough”. My question is; where do I “store” the `TcpStream` so that it does live long enough?

I've tried different iterations of trying to store the `stream` on the `Connection` struct but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is a cut down version of the code:

```
use std::io::{self, BufReader, BufWriter};
use std::net::TcpStream;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Connection<'a> {
    reader: BufReader<&'a TcpStream>,
    writer: BufWriter<&'a TcpStream>,
}

impl<'a> Connection<'a> {
    pub fn new(stream: TcpStream) -> io::Result<Self> {
        let connection = Self {
            reader: BufReader::new(&stream),
            writer: BufWriter::new(&stream),
        };

        Ok(connection)
    }
}

pub struct Search<'a> {
    connection: Connection<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Search<'a> {
    // fn new(stream: &'a TcpStream) -> Self {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:100").unwrap();
        let connection = Connection::new(stream).unwrap();

        Self { connection }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:100").unwrap();
    // Search::new(&stream);

    Search::new();
}
```

If I uncomment the commented-out lines it works.

Comment: You was close, https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=91088e29b5192d2e2475c7387ec7d88b, consider use [`bufstream`](https://docs.rs/bufstream/0.1.4/bufstream/)

Comment: @Stargateur thanks for taking a look. I wasn't clear enough in my original question but I'd really like the API to look like the un-commented code. So the `::new()` function is responsible for creating the `TcpStream`. I don't think the other question is a duplicate because I'm still not clear on where to “store” the stream.

Comment: You can't see: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: Aha! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct explains it perfectly. Thanks very much.

Comment: If anyone has any other ideas on how to structure this code, please let me know.

Comment: As I said, use bufstream, https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e4faf993fc0c49cf5d9da45d5938ec6